# remainder (%) operator c#

Tags: c#, operators, modulo

It's a very basic question, I would just like to understand a little better how this operator actually works.

This code is taking a number from the user and then getting the sum of the individual digits:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number: ");
int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int sum = 0;

while (number / 10 > 0)
{
    ***sum += number % 10;***
    number = number / 10;
}

sum += number;
Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", "Sum of digits is: ", sum.ToString());
Console.ReadKey();`
sum += number % 10;
```

The way I'm interpreting it is that because sum = 0, it basically takes the number, divides it by 10 and then assigns the remainder of that to the sum?

Is this right or have I misunderstood it?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: "takes the number, divides it by 10 and then assigns the remainder of that to the sum?" You´ve got it. Hower the [docs on the modulo operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/modulus-operator) would surely have told you the same.

Comment: "because sum = 0" - well only on the first iteration. Rather than think of that as a special case, why not just consider it always adding the remainder to the current value of `sum`?

Comment: Rather than 'assigns the remaindeer to the sum' it 'adds the remainder to the sum'

Comment: In particular, if you separate out your understanding of the `+=` operator from the `%`, it'll be simpler: `int remainder = number % 10; sum += remainder;`. Now you can concentrate on one thing at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Output you can understand every steps and what's happening in every step

```
using System;
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number: ");
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int sum = 0;
    while (number> 0)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Steps");
      Console.WriteLine("--------------");
      Console.WriteLine("Digits: "+ (number % 10));
      sum = sum + (number % 10);
       Console.WriteLine("sum: "+ sum);
      number = number / 10;
      Console.WriteLine("number after number/10: "+ (number).ToString());
      Console.WriteLine("--------------");
    }
Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", "Sum of digits is: ", sum.ToString());
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Please enter a number: 
 9874
Steps
--------------
Digits: 4
sum: 4
number after number/10: 987
--------------
Steps
--------------
Digits: 7
sum: 11
number after number/10: 98
--------------
Steps
--------------
Digits: 8
sum: 19
number after number/10: 9
--------------
Steps
--------------
Digits: 9
sum: 28
number after number/10: 0
--------------
Sum of digits is: 28
```

Comment: Thank you, thats exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Welcome!! @RowanFernando

Answer (score 5):

Let's take a number = 512:
Now in while loop:

```
sum += number % 10;
```

sum is like

```
sum = sum + number % 10
```

and `number % 10` is

```
512 % 10 = 2
```

HOW ??

```
512 = 50 * 10 + 2
```

the above `2` is the remainder.
Now

```
number = number / 10
```

makes the `number 512 to 51`

This is how for each iteration your code is adding each digit to the sum.
So, you got it right that it is calculating the sum of each digit of a number.

Answer (score 1):

% is called modulus and gives you the remainder when dividing

if you remember long division it was something like:

```
16/5=3 remainder 1
```

the modulus operator will return 1 when done like

```
16%5
```

depending on how you use it it can be very useful... you can use it in if conditions, loops, etc...